# Dictionary program/website that has IPA+recording for as many words as possible

Tags: pronunciation, dictionaries, ipa

I usually use [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aMain_Page) as my English dictionary. The main things that I'm interested in are (1) IPA transcriptions and (2) voice recordings of each word.

The problem is that Wiktionary doesn't have those for as many words as I would want.

Is there a more complete solution? A dictionary which has those 2 things for more words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dictionary.cambridge.org seems to have what you want.